# Should I seperate classes for individual players in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, class, optimization

I’m currently working on a text-based game in C++, with 2 players. Both of the players have the same exact functions with the same sets of variables, but would it be more optimized to seperate player actions into 2 different classes?

The way I’m currently running it is by using a parameter in functions for the players to distinguish which player’s turn it was. However, there is a lot of copy pasting in it, and the conditionals for it look a little messy. It works, it’s just hard to read the code.

Here’s an example of the same function, same set of variables:

```
    int territoryPrice = 10000;
    
    if (player == 1){
        if (pOneMoney >= territoryPrice){
            pOneMoney -= territoryPrice;
            pOneTerritories++;
        }
        else if (pOneMoney < territoryPrice){
            cout << "You don't have enough money!\n\n";
        }
    }
    else if (player == 2) {
        if (pTwoMoney >= territoryPrice){
            pTwoMoney -= territoryPrice;
            pTwoTerritories++;
        }
        else if (pTwoMoney < territoryPrice){
            cout << "You don't have enough money!\n\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The parameter “player” is checked and alters stats accordingly.

Comment: If you say the functions are exactly the same, then why are there conditions? Can you show some code?

Comment: One player class, two player *objects*.

Comment: What are the differences between the two players? Are they of the same *kind*? Are they implemented differently? A [mre] would help.

Comment: There should be a single class, with "money" and "number of territories" as members. And two objects of this class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exact point of classes is to reduce this duplication. You write the functions and variables once, then you can very easily create as many copies of the whole thing as you need.

You should write a class `Player` and then you can create two variables from this class, one for each player.

Like this:

```
struct Player {
    int money = 100000;
    int territories = 0;
};
Player player1;
Player player2;
```

(Notice I used `struct` instead of `class`. You'll learn the reason later. In C++, structs and classes are the same thing. I suggest using `struct` until you learn it)

Variables and functions inside the class are referenced with the `.` operator, as in

```
std::cout << "Player 1's money: " << player1.money << std::endl;
```

Your code can be re-written without duplication by using a pointer to say which player's turn it is, then we can make the computer always look at the current player:

```
// make player be a Player* variable that points to player1 or player2.
// player->money is a shortcut for (*player).money

int territoryPrice = 10000;
    
if (player->money >= territoryPrice){
    player->money -= territoryPrice;
    player->terrorities++;
}
else if (player->money < territoryPrice){ // you don't need this 'if' by the way
    cout << "You don't have enough money!\n\n";
}
```

If you wanted a game with many players you could even make an array: `Player players[6];` or if you don't know the number of players until the game runs, you could use a resizable array with `std::vector<Player> players;` and you could use loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    std::cout << players[i].name << "'s score is: " << players[i].score << std::endl;
```

---

Note: it would also be possible to do this without classes or pointers, by using arrays. You could have `int pMoney[2];` and `int pTerrorities[2];` and then if you make it so `player` is either 0 or 1, you can write `pMoney[player]` to talk about the current player's money and `pTerrorities[player]` to talk about their territories.

Comment: For when you said “I suggest using struct until you learn it)” did you mean you suggest using class until I learn struct or should I learn struct now to apply it?

Comment: @Selisine I mean I suggest using struct until you learn what the difference is (it is related to access modifiers and I assume you don't know about access modifiers)

Comment: @user253715 Oh okay, thank you. Currently trying to figure out the dereference pointer as well.

Comment: @Selisine do you know about pointers?

Comment: @user253715 I have a rough idea. I know you find the memory address of a variable using & and the * to tell you the value of the memory address that was pointed to.

Comment: @Selisine you could also think of it like a name for another variable and you can change which variable that is. Like you have this pointer variable "current_player" (or just "player") and it points to either "player1" or "player2"

Comment: @user253715 Oh that clears things up a lot. I was reading up on old documentation for C++ and it made my head hurt a little, so an analogy like this helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @Selisine yeah, the *address* is just how the CPU calls the variable. CPUs don't deal in names, only numbers. The compiler helps figure out an address for each variable. You call it player1, the CPU calls it 58631103798 or whatever.